# JQuery galleria recommendation

Tags: jquery, galleria

I've been using JQuery galleria(http://galleria.aino.se/). Problem is that the new version is quite buggy, does anyone have a recommendation on another plugin to use ? I'd like it if it was hosted on github, under active development and manages bugs\issues on github directly too.

Answer (score 3):

I don't like that galleria either so I am going to try a similar one, called pikachoose:
http://pikachoose.com/demo/

Otherwise I did use Cycle plugin before as well, which I think is great, so many options..

Answer (score 1):

[Shadowbox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/index.html) might work for you. You can see an example gallery half way down the main page.

It's not free for commercial use, though. :-(

Another one I've looked at is [Cycle](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/).